# Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on integer

Tags: php

```
    $total = $_POST['total'];
$myselect = $_POST['myselect'];

$t = '2';
// function date
$date_go = "$rn_gostart"; //กำหนดค้นวันที่เริ่ม
$date_end = "$rn_endstart"; //กำหนดค้นวันที่กลับ
$datetime1 = new DateTime($date_go);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($date_end);
$datetotal = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

if ($datetotal = 0 ) {
$total = '1800';
}else {
 $total= $datetotal->format('%a') * 1800*$myselect;  //ผลการคำนวณ
}
```

Problem is that if I book a day like this: 10.07.2559 * 07.10.2559 = 0, but if it will book a 10/01/2559 * 11/07/2559. It is normal

Comment: I still don't understand what is the expected output of your code. Why are you multiplying dates?

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
if ($datetotal = 0 )
```

to:

```
if ($datetotal == 0 )
```

Your current code assigns zero to `$datetotal`, making your code fail on the line:

```
$total = $datetotal->format('%a') * 1800*$myselect;
```

The format `%a` is incorrect. It must be replaced by [a valid format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), depending on what you want to do.

Comment: not work  it show  0  10.07.2559 * 07.10.2559 = 0

Comment: The same day, it must be presented in 1800.

Comment: I don't think this format is valid to be parsed in datetime: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: @Jeff you're right. I updated my answer, thanks.

Comment: To date, the same date  10/07/2559 * 07/10/2559 = 1800

Comment: @Jocelyn I actually ment "10.07.2559" to be not valid!

Comment: @Jeff 2559 is the current year in the Thai calendar, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_Thailand)

Comment: @Jocelyn yeah, seems so! Still I think it has to be formatted with `/` or `-` to be parsed/understood by `datetime`. None of the examples in the manual are with dots (although this is 'my' correct writing as an austrian/european).

Answer (score 0):

if i am not use if else and use

```
$total = $_POST['total'];
$myselect = $_POST['myselect'];

// function date
$date_go = "$rn_gostart"; //กำหนดค้นวันที่เริ่ม
$date_end = "$rn_endstart"; //กำหนดค้นวันที่กลับ
$datetime1 = new DateTime($date_go);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($date_end);
$datetotal = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$total= $datetotal->format('%a') * 1800 * $myselect;
```

10.07.2559 * 08.10.2559 = 1800

but 10.07.2559 * 07.10.2559 = 0

Comment: Why are you posting that? If you want to update your question there is an "edit" link below the question.